# How to call imported helperfunction in react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a CRA app and trying to sort for some reason it wont call the helper function called sortModel:

```
let rankingCommercial = 
      {
        'Actual':1,
        'Projected':2,
        'Proforma':3
      }



    let rankingAgribusiness = 
    {
      'Historical':1,
      'Actual':2,
      'Projected':3,
      'Proforma':4
    }

export default function sortModel(item1,item2)
{
    console.log('start sort function')
    if (item1.model ==='Commercial'  && item2.model ==='Commercial') {


        if (rankingCommercial[item1.type]> rankingCommercial[item2.type])
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            return -1;
        }
    }

    if (item1.model ==='Agribusiness' && item2.model ==='Agribusiness' ){
        if (rankingAgribusiness[item1.rank]> rankingAgribusiness[item2.rank])
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            return -1;
        }
    }



}
```

The app.js looks like this:

```
import help from './sortHelper.js'
```

...

```
let result = myData.sort(help.sortModel)
```

Looks like the sort is not called? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have a look at [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) and [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) on MDN to learn more about how to use modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your app.js you are calling

```
let result = myData.sort(help.sortModel)
```

and importing `help` from `'./sortHelper.js'`, however, in your sort model script you are exporting sortModel as the default and therefore when you are importing `help`, `help` becomes an alias for the sortModel function, i.e. sortModel is not a nested property of help but is help itself.

If sortModel were to be accessed as a nested property, in your sortModel script, instead of having:

```
export default function sortModel(item1,item2)
  {
     // your sort function code here 
  }
```

You would instead have something like :

```
export default helpFunctions = {
  sortModel: (item1, item1) {
    // your sort function code here
  }
}
```

and then in your app.js when importing as `import help from './sortHelper.js'` , you would be able to access it via help.sortModel

Answer (score 1):

Because you use export default, just call

```
let result = myData.sort(help)
```